# Does a bend in a DC current carrying conductor radiate EM waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

An accelerated electric charge creates a transverse em wave radiated at the speed of light. But a dc current negotiating any bend in the conductor must undergo accelerating forces to change spatial direction. This must surely generate some, albeit extremely weak, em radiation?

Comment: I suspect that there may be a very small Bremsstrahlung emission from the bent DC current, but I suspect that it would be very difficult to detect. Or absolutely I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a radiated field requires a changing current density, $\vec J$, and a DC current implies $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec J=0$.

If you think about a single charges accelerating around the bend then yes, there are some radiative terms to the Lienard Wiechert fields. But you do not have a single charge, you have a DC current. The various charges cancel out the radiative terms leaving only the non-radiative terms.

This can be seen more easily in Jefimenko's equations:$$ \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}, t) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \int \left[\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^3}\rho(\mathbf{r}', t_r) + \frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^2}\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \rho(\mathbf{r}', t_r)}{\partial t} - \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|}\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r}', t_r)}{\partial t} \right] dV'$$$$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}, t) = -\frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \left[\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^3} \times \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r}', t_r) + \frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^2} \times \frac{1}{c} \frac{\partial \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r}', t_r)}{\partial t} \right] dV'$$ for DC sources this simplifies to $$ \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}, t) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \int \left[\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^3}\rho(\mathbf{r}', t_r)  \right] dV'$$$$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}, t) = -\frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \left[\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^3} \times \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r}', t_r) \right] dV'$$
Notice that for the DC Jefimenko's equations both the E field and the B field fall off as $|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^{-2}$ which means that the energy stays strongly localized near the sources. It does not radiate.

Comment: Bremsstrahlung (or “braking radiation”) is the radiation given off by free electrons that are deflected (i.e., accelerated) in the electric fields of charged particles and the nuclei of atoms. More than a single charge here! Sorry, Dale, don't understand your reasoning. Have you a reference to your comments you can share?

Comment: @adlibber I don’t have a reference but I can demonstrate what I mean for a simple circular loop. It will take me a bit to write up the math. Hopefully tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks Dale. No radiation from a circular loop (see Ohanian Physics 2nd Ed question 19 p 868) because the radiation is aligned in the direction of electron motion and therefor will be cancelled out with the multitude of accelerated electrons in a current. However in a current negotiating a bend there is an initial deceleration in line with the motion and a final acceleration, once again in line with the motion, resulting in the current radiation propagating in phase in the axial direction.

Comment: The shape of the loop is unimportant. Any shape loop has $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec J=0$ at DC. But more complicated shapes will quickly exceed my ability to do the math. If you are focused on the shape then you are missing the key physics. DC implies steady current and therefore no radiation. I can try a square loop maybe

Comment: The critical point is how the radiation cancels. This is easily demonstrated in the case of a circular loop where the acceleration is constant and radial. However in the case of a straight conductor encountering a bend there has to be a deceleration in line with the current flow. This results in an axial rather than a longitudinal propagation of energy.

Comment: You are still focused on the shape. It is not relevant. An EM wave requires a changing source, which is absent for DC. Ask yourself: when would the peak of the wave be emitted? I will try a square loop.

Comment: I have realigned my thinking and you must be right, Dale! Any radiated energy must be funded and that can only be sourced by a change in absolute momentum aka electrical current. If it can be shown that a DC circuit rate of change of current (density) is entirely due to resistive effects then the shape of the circuit conductor cannot radiate energy.  BUT in that case what about the solitary electron?

Comment: @adlibber sorry, I tried the square loop and I cannot symbolically invert the retarded time. The solitary electron radiates because $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec J \ne 0$.

Comment: Having now switched my view, Dale, where does a solitary electron in a circular path gets its radiation energy from?possibly from the field that’s providing the centripetal balancing force? Or is it simply from its own kinetic energy that will eventually cause it to spiral into its centre of rotation?

Comment: @adlibber unless you add energy (e.g. in a cyclotron or a synchotron) then it will lose energy and eventually spiral in as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/26PmM.jpg I have added an additional paragraph demonstrating the conclusion using Jefimenko's equations, which is as good as I can do

Comment: I think you’ve done pretty good, Dale. As you can probably gather I didn’t get near a PhD in Physics ;-( I do have a relative who is a particle physicist at CERN and works on the CMS experiment but I think all this stuff would either be way above or below his head!

Comment: Thank you Dale. You don’t by any chance have a qualitative description of just how a dc current comprising a single electron radiates do you? This radiated energy must be funded by presumably a reduction in the charge’s velocity.

Comment: There is no such thing as a DC current comprising a single electron. A single electron current necessarily has $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec J \ne 0$ so it cannot be DC

Comment: therefore to qualify as a DC current the rate of change of the current density must be zero. Of course that depends entirely on the scale of inspection. Patently a single electron cannot provide such a result, maybe a quadrillion? Him, tricky. Has this ever be defined?

Comment: This article ”Why doesn’t a steady current loop radiate?”.  http://kirkmcd.princeton.edu/examples/steadycurrent.pdf covers the issue and addresses Ohanian’s question mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0):

The power radiated by a charge with constant acceleration is
$$P=\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{a^2}{c^3}.$$ For an electron going around a circular bend of radius (let's say) one centimeter the acceleration is
$$a=\frac{v_d^2}{r}$$ where $v_d$ is the drift velocity for an electron that's around a millimeter per second. Once you put all the numbers together the power radiated by a single electron in this situation comes out to around $10^{-61}$ watts while the kinetic energy of the electron is around $10^{-37}$ J, so we're talking about more than $10^{16}$ years for the electron to radiate away all its energy. This is all to say that the radiation emmited is negligible.

Comment: Thanks aftershave! My initial thinking but if that were that the case then a circular dc conductor loop would radiate and my betters tell me that is not the case. There is also a strong qualitative case for it not being so. In your example there would be a vanishingly small change in current density through the bend and Maxwell has something to say about that.

Comment: The radiation from a full circular loop cancels because of symmetry but a bend in a wire need not be a full loop.

Comment: That was my original supposition, aftershave, but @Dale (see above) told me that thinking was wrong (and he's got a PhD).